# Apply css to last character in WordPress menu items

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to apply some css to the current viewed menu item on a WordPress site. I can apply css to the whole item, but want to apply something to specifically just the last character.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no cross browser solution to achieve it using pure CSS.

You can either using PHP or javascript to get the last character and style it or you can wrap that last character in another element like `<span>` and style it using css as normally.

---

EDIT: Here is the javascript approach:

```
<p class="test">This is a test</p>

var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
for(i=0; i<targets.length; i++) {
    var html = targets[i].innerHTML;
    targets[i].innerHTML = html.substr(0, html.length-1)
        + "<span class='lastChar'>"
        + targets[i].innerHTML.substr(-1)
        + "</span>";
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b5mZD/)**

Comment: Yeah, I gathered it's not possible with just CSS. I do wish that there was a last-letter pseudo operator like first-letter!

Any thoughts on how I might be able to go about creating the required PHP or JS?

Comment: sadly there is no `::last-letter` selector

Comment: Thanks so much for going to that trouble! I am now trying to run a similar script minus the for loop as there will only be one item that needs to have the last character modified. Can you please take a quick look at the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b5mZD/2/) to let me know where I'm going wrong? Thanks :-)

Comment: @oldo.nicho You need to remove redundant closing `})` as well as targeting first `target`, so use `target[0]`. Here is the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5mZD/3/

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Felix! I had assumed that given there only being one target object that it wouldn't of created an array and therefore wouldn't need to target target[0], but as you can tell I'm new to all this and am learning every step along the way. Thanks for helping me sort this out :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Felix said, there is no cross browser solution to achieve it using pure CSS. I would reccommend writing simple js code to split menu item and add span with class to last letter.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  var item = $('.current-menu-item').children().html();
  $('.current-menu-item').children().html(item.substr(0, item.length - 1) + '<span class="last">' + item.substr(-1) + '</span>');
});
```